# R: subset a dataframe by factor levels with a second condition

Tags: r, subset

I am looking to create subsets of Contact.ID's occurring in certain Terms but not other.

To explain a bit better, this is a snapshot of my dataset:

```
df <- c(Contact.ID, Date.Time, Age, Gender, Attendance)

Contact.ID       Date    Time    Age   Gender   Attendance   Term 
1   A       2012-10-06 18:54:48   37    Male         30      Term1
2   A       2013-03-12 20:50:18   37    Male         30      Term2
3   A       2013-05-24 20:18:44   37    Male         30      Term3
4   B       2012-11-15 16:58:15   27  Female         40      Term1 
5   B       2012-12-23 10:57:02   27  Female         40       WB
6   B       2013-01-11 17:31:22   27  Female         40      Term2
7   B       2013-02-18 18:37:00   27  Female         40      Term2
8   C       2013-02-22 17:46:07   40    Male         5       Term2
9   C       2013-02-27 11:21:00   40    Male         5       Term2
10  D       2012-10-28 14:48:33   20  Female         12      Term1
```

My issue is, I need to create further segmentation dependent on Contact.ID's

So the groups I am looking to create are:

- Term 1 Only --> ID's that are only present in term 1 but not in any other term (ID D for example)
- Term 2 Only ---> ID's that are only present in term 2 but not in any other term (ID C for example)
- Term 1 & 2 --> ID's that are only in term 1 and 2 not term 3(ID B for example)
- Term 1 & 2 & 3 --> ID's that are present in all terms (ID A for example)

I have tried different ways of adding conditions to the `subset` and also tried `df[ which ()]` sort of function  and `subset(df, () & () & !())` but I cant seem to get it right.

Any suggestions? I sincerely appreciate the help.

Comment: you can try something like `intersect(!(Term1$Contact.ID %in% Term2$Contact.ID), !(Term1$Contact.ID %in% Term3$Contact.ID))` for exclusive in Term 1. And so on.

Comment: Its tough to help without having a way to easily reproduce your example, but have you tried creating a flag variable in your data frame based on the conditions you laid out for Term1, 2, 3?  ( for example, create a new column where 1 would = all rows within term1 time frame, 2 = all rows within term2 time frame etc.) then you should be able to easily subset too.  It will also prevent you from having many dataframes.

Comment: @abhiieor thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately that only creates a `value` of  'logi [1 : 2] False True` , so it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Sheila, no I have not tried that yet! great Idea! I'll give that a go now.

Comment: @Sheila, hey, I have managed to create a new column defining what term the date belongs to, but I am still stuck on how to define the next step. As now all I have is an additional column stating the first distinction, but I have too many ID's to manually describe the next step.. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i dont know what the WB is in your data set, but I think you can follow this code to fill in what you're looking for. We basically just need to filter on the unique number of terms that each Contact.ID are in and then make sure the terms are correct. I am not counting "WB" as one of the terms since it doesn't look like you are.

```
library(data.table)

dat = read.table("clipboard", header = TRUE)
setDT(dat)

dat[ , 'Num_Unique_Terms' := uniqueN(Term[Term != "WB"]), by = Contact.ID]

term1 = dat[Num_Unique_Terms == 1 & Term == "Term1"]
term2 = dat[Num_Unique_Terms == 1 & Term == "Term2"]
terms12and3 = dat[Num_Unique_Terms == 3]


dat[ , 'All_1_or_2' := ifelse(all(Term[Term != "WB"] %in% c("Term1", "Term2")), 1, 0), by = Contact.ID]
dat[ , 'All_2_or_3' := ifelse(all(Term[Term != "WB"] %in% c("Term2", "Term3")), 1, 0), by = Contact.ID]

term1and2 = dat[All_1_or_2 == 1 & Num_Unique_Terms == 2]
term2and3 = dat[All_2_or_3 == 1 & Num_Unique_Terms == 2]
```

Comment: Hey @Kristofersen, thank you so much! This seems to work but to make sure it does, I have tried to create all groups possible to see if my count of ID's adds up and I am having one struggle: 
after creating term1, term2, term3, term1and2 and term1and2and3, I have tried to create term2and3, but I cant seem to get that line right. could you maybe please help?

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!! I am still not getting it right tho. Basically, I have 6593 subjects (Contact.ID). When I create the different subsets I get term1(964 ID's), term2(776ID’s), term3(490ID’s), term1&2&3(2,674ID's), term1&2(1,689ID's) and term2&3(1,689ID's). This exceeds my ID count by 1,689 and as the groups are exclusive it should be exactly 6593. Terms2&3 values have many subjects only in term2, which is wrong. I had thought I didn't create the subset correctly but I did have the same code as you.. any idea where my mistake could be? Again, thanks for your help!

Comment: WB was just another subsection, like a 'term4' but I removed them by extending my term 1, 2 and 3 parameters.

Comment: sorry, but what do you mean by that? The 'Num_Unique_Terms' values? they are all 1, 2 or 3 depending on what we chose in the given data.frame

Comment: I have tried both ways, both give me the same result

Comment: ~A   Term1 3
~A   Term2 3
~A   Term2 3
~A   Term2 3
~A   Term2 3
~A   Term3 3
~A   Term3 3
~B   Term3 1
~C   Term2 1
~C   Term2 1
~C   Term2 1

Here is a part of the data: ~ID Term Unique.. does that help in any way?

Comment: I figured out the issue but do not know how to resolve it. So basically because we assigned 2 to all ID's with 2 term entries, so term1&2 or 2&3, when we group them with the code of `terms1and2 = df[!Term %in% c("Term3") & Num_Unique_Terms == 2]` and `terms2and3 = df[Num_Unique_Terms == 2 & Term %in% c("Term2", "Term3")]` or `terms2and3 = Gym[Num_Unique_Terms == 2 & !Term %in% c("Term1")]` we include both times the ID that has a 2 and 'term2', which is why those lines are in both data frames and ID's are split and spread.

Comment: `unique(Gym$Term)`
`[1] "Term1" "Term2" "Term3"`

I have tried the line you just suggested too and it doesn't work because it still includes all ID's that have Term2 and a `unique` number 2, whether that ID entry belongs to 1&2 or 2&3

Comment: Sorry if I am not explaining it well. So I have the unique value 2 assigned to all ID's that have 2 terms. Those could be term1&2 or term2&3. when I run that code, it selects all unique values that have a term2. This means it separates some entries of one ID if the others have term1 for example. 

so if person A has Term 1,Term1, Term2 it will have the unique value 2 and if person B has Term2, Term3, Term3 it will also have the value 2. Now if we run the code for term2&3 it will give the 3rd entry of Person A and all entries of person B, which is why the data overlaps

Comment: :( I don't understand. I am using your code exactly but when I look at the data.frame of terms2and3, it shows me for example two entries of ID A in term2 with unique value 2 but that ID has 7 attendances, so 5 must be term1 and got excluded. could it have to do with my variable types maybe?

Comment: Awesome! this makes a lot more sense now! I am missing 153 ID's somewhere but I'll figure that out. This now makes a lot more sense! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @ Kristofersen
Hey, there is still something not right, could you maybe help me figure this out? 

Basically, the first attemped where the unique 2 was double counted, the overall ID's in that group matched my ID count perfectly (1,689/6593ID's) but wit the second approach, although the data gets split, I lost 153ID's. So now I have term1and2 with 954ID's and term2and3 with 582, but this equals 1536 instead of 1689ID's, so 153ID's got lost somewhere in the process as all other groups (term1, term2, term3 and term1and2and3) have the same ID count as before. Any idea what could have happened?

Comment: @Fee I think i'd have to see how you're summing everything up. Since there are no duplicate Contact.ID you could compare the unique count (uniqueN) of the Contact.ID in the original dataframe to the count of each of the terms summed up. If that matches then you know the Contact.ID have been split up and are only in 1 group each.

Comment: @ Kristofersen Hey! Found them! Just a thought error.. they belong to Term1and3. The code works perfectly! Thank you.